# Align everything left, one after the other - apart from last item on the right

Tags: css

A common layout is to have content on the left, and meta-data on the right in some form of box. I would like to know if it's possible to achieve this without two separate inner containers, like so:

```
<div class="topic">
  <h2>Topic title</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dorom</p>
  <p class="meta">
    <span class="date">2 hours ago</span>
    <span class="author">author</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Requirements:

- Everything that comes before .meta should be laid out nicely on the left, with the meta-data on the right.
- Should take into account long titles
- Meta-data on the right should be top aligned to the parent container

I can't think of a way to achieve this using the DOM above, in a fluid manner (no fixed-widths).

Demo of how it *should* look:
https://codepen.io/deanooo/pen/vYKwPxx

Comment: Pretty easy to achieve using flexbox on `.topic`, and a `margin-left:auto` on `.meta`.

Comment: `div.topic > P:last-of-type { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

It seems I misunderstood the problem and with the correct HTML there are other ways to do this but I will stick with the grid approach.

```
<div class="topic">
  <h2>Supports Long Title</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dorom</p>
  <div class="meta">
    <span class="date">2 hours ago</span>
    <span class="author">author</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Cheers!

https://codepen.io/yorsaquing/pen/rNLggpr

Comment: This is not using the desired HTML. The meta-data should be grouped.

Answer (score 0):

One (admittedly old-school) way to achieve this effect is:

- give the parent `div` a `padding-right` to create space for the sidebar
- position the sidebar using `position: absolute` and `top` and `right` co-ordinates

---

**Working Example:**

```css
.topic {
  position: relative;
  padding: 12px 196px 12px 12px;
  background-color: rgb(191, 191, 191);
}

.meta {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-right: 12px;
  padding: 12px;
  width: 160px;
  background-color: rgb(95, 95, 95);
}

.meta span {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
```

```html
<div class="topic">
  <h2>Topic title</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dorom</p>
  <p class="meta">
    <span class="date">2 hours ago</span>
    <span class="author">author</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: By absolutely positioning this it has the potential to overflow long-titles, and not hold "layout"

Comment: @Dean - I'm not following what you mean by _"overflow long titles"_ and _"hold layout"_.